# Why these blocks are positioned incorrectly, everything seems to be right?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite a beginner with HTML/CSS/JS. I tried to try things like the "display:" etc.
Everything seemed to work fine, except one thing. The blocks I added should be exactly on the same line, but the right one is always a bit more down than the left one. I tried adding height, changing values etc. but nothing seemed to help, so I decided to post it here.
Also, the button "alert" somewhy seems not to work?

https://jsfiddle.net/6qwqjctu/2/

```
<body background="assets/images/wallpaper.png">
    <header style="font-size:40px" class="indextitle">
<strong>Testing</strong>

    </header>
    <br>
    <br>
    <section class="firstblock">
<code>
<strong>1st new: </strong> <div id="dn1">None</div>
<strong>2nd new: </strong> <div id="dn2">None</div>
<strong>3rd new: </strong> <div id="dn3">None</div>
<strong>4th new: </strong> <div id="dn4">None</div>
</code>

    </section>
    <br>
    <br>
    <section class="secondblock">
<code>
<strong>First: </strong> <div id="d1">None</div>
<strong>Second: </strong> <div id="d2">None</div>
<strong>Third: </strong> <div id="d3">None</div>
<strong>4th: </strong> <div id="d4">None</div>

</code>

    </section>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr id="clear">
    <section class="buttonone" onclick="alertaction()">alert</section>
    <footer>
        <p style="font-size:25px">&copy; Nobody</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have 2 `<br/>` between your sections. Remove those.

So you will end up with this:

```
<section class="firstblock">
    <code>
        <strong>1st new: </strong> <div id="dn1">None</div>
        <strong>2nd new: </strong> <div id="dn2">None</div>
        <strong>3rd new: </strong> <div id="dn3">None</div>
        <strong>4th new: </strong> <div id="dn4">None</div>
    </code>
</section>
<section class="secondblock">
    <code>
        <strong>First: </strong> <div id="d1">None</div>
        <strong>Second: </strong> <div id="d2">None</div>
        <strong>Third: </strong> <div id="d3">None</div>
        <strong>4th: </strong> <div id="d4">None</div>
    </code>
</section>
```

About the button:

Avoid using `onClick` attribute. Use click listeners instead. Also, if its a button, use the `button` tag.

Something like this:

```js
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');

bar.onclick = function(event) {
  alert('click')
}
```

```html
<button id="bar">Alert</button>
```

Comment: That does work, but what about the button - why doesn't it work?

Comment: @ThomasTom edited about the button. adapt to your current code by adding an id to the button.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is used for line breaks which is causing the problem here and I'm confused why you're trying to use `<br>` tag after first `<section>`.

I'm also confused about your heavy use of `<section>` everywhere. I changed the button from `<section>` to normal `<button>`. 
Check the updated code: http://plnkr.co/edit/cNgXcU5dNoGmRPD6Hu10?p=info

Click to see in-detailed [difference between `<section>` and `<div>`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)