# make: *** No rule to make target `clean'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

I was walking through [this](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html) tutorial, where I had to create this `make` file:

```
 CFLAGS=-wall  -g

 clean:
   rm  -f  ex1
```

When I type this command:

> $ make clean

I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

I made sure that I'm using TABS. Why am I getting this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the name of your _makefile_?

Comment: It is a TextEdit (on MAC OS X) file called "make"

Comment: I think you need then `make -f <makefilename> clean`

Comment: if you created your file with TextEdit, chances are that it saved with an extension. Have you removed the extension from the file? Also, nameless answer is pretty accurate as well. Follow the identation rules

Comment: Make sure you follow your tutorial, it says "Save this file as Makefile in your current directory. Make automatically assumes there's a file called Makefile and will just run it. "

Comment: Don't use `make` as the filename. Use `Makefile` as the tutorial says. If you want to use a non-standard name then you need to use `make -f make` or whatever other name you chose.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Took your replies into account, I now get the following error: "Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: **That** error is about spaces instead of tabs on the recipe lines.

Comment: Yes, I think it worked now. Thanks everyone for your kind replies.

Comment: @Simplicity any reason you never accepted an answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, as indicated by a few comments on the post is that you named your file `make` instead of the traditional `Makefile` (or alternate names `GNUMakefile` and `makefile` that GNU make supports).

See [What Name to Give Your Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names) in the GNU make manual.

If you want to use an alternate name (like `make`) then you need to tell `make` to use that file with the `-f` flag (also mentioned in that section of the manual).

```
make -f make
```

The `missing separator` error is caused by incorrect indentation in the makefile. Spaces instead of tabs on recipe lines, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing your indentation is borked. Make is *very, very* specific in how files should be indented.

Your file should look like this:

```
CFLAGS=-wall -g

clean:
        rm -f ex1
```

Notice how clean is all the way left in the file (has no whitespace in front of it), and how there are two tabs (represented here by 8 spaces because I have no way of representing tabs on SO...)

basically, Make is an ancient program that has very, VERY particular rules as to how things are done. Be careful and follow the indent rules as closely as you possibly can.

Comment: No. Target names can have whitespace in front of them. The recipe lines can't though. They need *only* a tab (and only one tab though more is fine). And a tab *is* eight spaces.

Comment: For the TABS under "clean". I used two TABS before "rm", but still having the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I was under the impression that targets should not have whitespace in front of them.

Also, Make treats the first target as the default target (what we traditionally call 'all'), so if 'clean' is your only target, it will get treated as the default.

Comment: In my original code, I didn't have a space before the target. It seems the space showed in my question. I removed the space from the question.

Comment: No. Target names can have whitespace in front of them. The recipe lines can't though. They need *only* a tab.