# What is Difference Between Section Tag in HTML5 and same section define in div class="section"

Tags: css, html

Please Give me details what is difference between bellow code

```
         <section >
          Some text goes here...
         </section>
```

and same write like inside div

```
          <div class="section">
                 Some text goes here...
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<section>` marks up a [section](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/), `<div>` marks up a generic block with
>   no associated semantics.

[See it here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)

Answer (score 0):

this is possibly a duplicate of [What is the difference between <section> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)

but to answer your question section tag is a html5 semantic tag that represents a generic section of a document or application