# Difference between <section> and <div> in <aside> sidebar

Tags: html, sidebar, semantic-markup

There are 2 ways I found to mark up a sidebar:

```
<aside id="sidebar">
    <section id="widget_1"></section>
    <section id="widget_2"></section>
    <section id="widget_3"></section>
</aside>
```

and

```
<aside id="sidebar">
     <div class="widget" id="widget_1"></div>
     <div class="widget" id="widget_2"></div>
     <div class="widget" id="widget_3"></div>
 </aside>
```

Please tell me what is difference between both approaches and which one must be used?

Comment: There is a pretty solid answer for your question within the above post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6941170/1089331 – Note: It's not the accepted answer. Semantic meaning is the difference, I'd use `<widget class="widget" id="widget_1">` personally. You don't *need* to use either one over the other (in this case).

Comment: Thanks brother, Yes i have read that post. It covers all possible aspects but i am concern about only sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Sections generally specify related groups of information - while div tags don't really specify anything and are usually used as children elements :)

If you want yo read up more, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div) which covers it pretty well in my opinion.

To answer your question, either will work - it's more a stylistic choice and how you want the information on your site to be organized.

Comment: so to design widgets we must always use sections right ??

Comment: Personally, I use `<div>` tags - as widgets don't really qualify as grouped information. If your css specifies `div.widget_1` or `section.widget_1` you'll need to use whichever one is used. Otherwise if the css just looks like `.widget_1{\\css}` it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest functional difference of what you're doing there is the semantic meaning difference between `<section>` and `<div>`.  `<div>` has no semantic meaning, use it for style, separation, add your own classes and ids, whatever.  On the other hand, `<section>` elements are typically supposed to have headings inside them, or at least gain an entry in the document outline.

In this case, I'd recommend starting with `<div>`, especially inside an `<aside>` element.