# What sort of tags, excluding div, can be used to make a login page with html5?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a login page but i'm not allowed to use div tags so i'm wondering what other html5 tags should i use to make the page more semantic? I've seen several tutorials use tags like  and im not sure which alternatives i should be using to this. I'm just a beginner in html5 so some explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It depends on what content you're going to be displaying/containing. For instance, a `<figure>` tag may be used for image content, or an `<article>` for forum/blog-like content

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for example the section tag `<section>` to wrap up the content of the login screen. This is used for elements that are connected to the same context.

[What is the difference between <section> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)