# Technical differences of div vs section vs article

Tags: html

Is there some **technical differences** between a **section**, **div** and an **article**?

**Edit:** I am not asking about when you **should** use it. I am talking about **specific technical differences**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between <section> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are asking for **technical**, and *not semantic* differences, here we go:

```js
app
  .querySelectorAll("*")
  .forEach(el => console.log(el.constructor.name));
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div></div>
  <section></section>
  <article></article>
</div>
```

As you can see, `div` has *its own* constructor interface, [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement), whereas `section` and `article` **do not have this**.

Instead, their constructor comes directly from [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) (which `HTMLDivElement` inherits from).

By what MDN says, the only actual addition `HTMLDivElement` receives is a property `align` (which has been marked *obsolete*).

Thus, it actually **does not have any different or additional properties** on top of also being an `HTMLElement`. Technically, it could now as well be an `HTMLElement` *only*, but to keep the web compatible with existing code, the `HTMLDivElement` interface cannot be removed, as there will be alot of existing  code that uses the interface. Removing it would break pages using such code.

Answer (score 0):

They express different semantics.

Articles are articles. Sections are sections. And divs are generic blocks with no semantics.

The semantics are used by tools like screen readers, search engines, and so on to identify what content is what. It can be used to treat some content as more important that others by a search engine or for navigating around a document by a screen reader.

Comment: So they have no difference technically? No special rules or something like that?

Comment: @PetroKoval — Different semantics *are* a technical difference.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not English native speaker. What do you mean under semantics, except: "human defined rules of where you **should** use them"?

Comment: @PetroKoval — The semantics are used by tools like screen readers, search engines, and so on to identify what content is what. It can be used to treat some content as more important that others by a search engine or for navigating around a document by a screen reader.

Comment: There it is! Thanks, it would be awesome if you paste this in your answer. :)

Comment: There is also a *real* technical difference, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624781/3744304