# Difference between <div> and <section> tags

Tags: html

What are the appropriate uses of `<div>` and `<section>` tags?

I started to learn html. I was reading something in the internet in this purpose. There, I see the following code and the question aroused inside me that why he used `<section>` tag here? He could have used `<div>` tag instead.

Code:

```
`<section class="chapter">
   <h2>My First Chapter</h2>
   <p>This is the first of my chapters. It doesn't say much.</p>
   <p>But it has two paragraphs!</p>
</section>
<section class="chapter">
   <h2>It Continues: The Second Chapter</h2>
   <p>Bla dee bla, dee bla dee bla. Boom.</p>
</section>`
```

Comment: See: [What is the difference between <section> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)

Answer (score 0):

They're similar but < section > is useful for browsers and screen readers to group content together. < div > is simply to help you with layout.
In this example, if div was used, yes, there would be no visible changes to you.